# Using attr data in jQuery

Tags: jquery, custom-attributes, attr

I'm pretty new to jQuery so this may be a pretty basic mistake, but is this right?

```
var maxFont = $('h2').attr('font-max');
jQuery('.jtextfill').textfill({ maxFontPixels: + maxFont });
```

The attribute of font-max is set in the html, but I am not successfully able to use it here for some reason.

I am trying to replace having to do something like this:

```
maxFontPixels: 72
```

In case there's a question, the html looks something like this:

```
<h2 font-max="[someValue]" >
```

I would greatly appreciate any help... thanks!

**UPDATE:** Solution was to remove the space between the '+' and the variable. Like I said, I'm a noob. Hope this helps.

Comment: Good question. `{ maxFontPixels: + maxFont }` What's with the plus? Did you try debugging with an `alert(maxFont)`?

Comment: did you try `var maxFont = $('h2:first').attr('font-max');`?  It may be that you are returning an array of elements instead of a specific element.

Comment: The `+` is the unary plus operator, which will convert the string into a number.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I just now used the alert and it did give me the value. The plus sign is just the result of trying to figure this out from various examples that were not quite right. Removing it does not resolve the issue, though.

Comment: @James - I am working with a number

Comment: It should work fine, if, as Jeremy said, one element is returned by `$('h2')`. Here's a similar working example: http://jsfiddle.net/qAcDe/1/

Comment: @MichaelDavis - `attr` will return a string, so the `+` will convert it to a number. But it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Thanks for all the quick responses. I got it working. The problem was the space between the '+' and the variable. Apparently it should be like this: +maxFont

Answer (score 0):

width this line of Code

```
var maxFont = $('h2').attr('font-max');
```

you get the 72.
If you want to write it into a DIV, SPAN or something else you can do this via

```
$('.theElementToDisplay').innerHTML(maxFont);
```

If you want to change the maxFont Value of the HTML Element you can set this with

```
$('h2').attr('font-max', 'yourValue');
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear from your question what exactly isn't working.

Anyway, don't use custom attributes, use data-* properties.

Change:

```
<h2 font-max="[someValue]" >
```

To:

```
<h2 data-font-max="[someValue]" >
```

And change:

```
var maxFont = $('h2').attr('font-max');
```

To:

```
var maxFont = $('h2').data('font-max');
```

While this is the better way to do custom attributes, it probably still won't fix your problem. Your problem is more likely with your call to `textfill`.

Comment: @BNL - You are right about the problem being in the call to the plugin. It works fine if I hard code the value so I think I am just missing the piece where I insert the variable into the call.

Comment: So does maxFont actually get the value or not? If you can alert the value of maxFont, you shouldn't have to do anything else.

Comment: @BNL - Yes, it alerted. I posted the solution in the comments above, but basically I had to remove the space between the '+' and the variable. I am going to take your advice and try converting to using a data property as you suggested.